# basic algebra inequalities

Tags: inequality

it's been a while since I worked with inequalities. Im trying to figure out the steps taken to go from $p > n^{1/3}$ to $p/n < n^{2/3}$

I am assuming the first step they did, is take the inverse of $p$, so
$p > n^{1/3} \Rightarrow p^{-1} < n^{1/3}$ then multiplied both sides by $n$.
So
$n/p < n^{2/3}$

Is this correct? I am just not sure if one could simply take an inverse of a number he pleases in an equation and reverse the inequalities.

Thank you

Comment: The inequality is not correct. $2>1^{1/3}=1$ but $2/1\not<1^{2/3}$

Comment: Thanks man, I should have checked for its truth before trying to figure it out. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Ok I figured it out. 
Here is how its done

Comment: $p > n^{1/3} \Rightarrow p^{-1} < n^{-1/3} \Rightarrow np^{-1} < nn^{-1/3} \Rightarrow n/p < n^{-1/3 + 1} = n^{2/3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct but you made several typos that it appears everything you say is wrong.

" Im trying to figure out the steps taken to go from $p>n^{1/3}$ to $p/n<n^{2/3}$"

You meant (I assume) to type $\frac np < n^{\frac 23}$.  $\frac pn < n^{\frac 23}$ is not a correct result.

"I am assuming the first step they did, is take the inverse of p
, so $p>n^{1/3}⇒p^{−1}<n^{1/3}$"

I assume you meant to type $p^{-1} < n^{-\frac 13}$ and not $p^{-1} < n^{\frac 13}$.

By coincidence the latter *is* true if $p > 1$ and $n > 1$ but it isn't true if $n < 1$.  And the latter will not get you anywhere.

"then multiplied both sides by n. So $n/p<n^{2/3}$"

$n^{-\frac 13}*n = n^{-\frac 13 + 1} = n^{\frac 23}$ so this would be correct.

However as you had incorrectly typed $n^{\frac 13}$, $n^{\frac 13}*n = n^{\frac 13 + 1} \ne n^{\frac 23}$ and so wouldn't be correct.  But as $n^{\frac 13}$ wasn't correct in the first place, this is ultimately correct.

So, yes, your reasoning was correct but you typos were all wrong.

Comment: Thanks man, I figured that down and posted the solution below. Thank you for the explanation tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out. For anyone who is curious

$p>n^{1/3}⇒p^{−1}<n^{−1/3}⇒np−1<nn^{−1/3}⇒n/p<n^{−1/3+1}=n^{2/3}$